# Access a list elements function in c++

Tags: c++, list, iterator

i have a list of Points.

```
class Point {
private:
    int xval, yval;
public:
    Point(int x=0, int y=0) {
        xval = x;
        yval = y;
    }

    int x() { return xval; }
    int y() { return yval; }

    friend bool operator== (const Point a,const Point b) {
        return (a.xval==b.xval && a.yval==b.yval);
    }
};
```

Now in main I want to look for certain points, if they exist in a list, and if so, i want to access the y-value of the point.

```
list<Point> coordinates;
for (list<Point>::iterator i = coordinates.begin(); i!=coordinates.end(); i++) {
    if(*i.y()>height) height = *i.y();
}
```

Now my question is how to acces the y() function of a point? Because this code gives me an error telling me, y is not element of 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>'

Comment: if(i->y()>height) height = i->y();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
 if((*i).y()>height) height = (*i).y();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `i->y()` or this: `(*i).y()`